# Sql union all optimization

Tags: sql

**hi guys, how do i optimize a query that joins too many tables. It takes about 5 seconds when I merge it using union all. waiting for your thoughts**

set nocount on;
select name,phone,id from members_89 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_92 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_156 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_180 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_188 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_189 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_194 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_202 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_206 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_208 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_209 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_210 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_211 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_213 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_215 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_219 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_220 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_222 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_233 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_243 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_244 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_246 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_249 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_252 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_253 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_255 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_261 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_262 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_265 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_274 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_298 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_319 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_326 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_327 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_335 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_340 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_341 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_343 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_344 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_345 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_348 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_349 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_352 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_353 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_357 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_358 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_359 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_360 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_361 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_362 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_363 Where id=1639
union all
select name,phone,id from members_364 Where id=1639
union all
.
.
.

Comment: Your question: "how do i optimize a query that joins too many tables" -> Simple answer: Join less tables. Without further information, I guess no one can help you. The issue is not UNION ALL here, but that you are selecting from so many tables. Why that?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a more basic problem with your database structure.  Generally speaking, having a large number of tables with the same column names is a code smell.  *Especially* if those table names are distinguished only by numeric suffixes.

So, instead of:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Members_1 (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(32),
    Phone VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE Members_2 (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(32),
    Phone VARCHAR(32)
);

-- ... a few hundred more like these
```

You should instead do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Members (
    TableID INTEGER,
    ID INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (TableID, ID),
    Name VARCHAR(32),
    Phone VARCHAR(32)
);
```

And then you can simply write your query as a single statement.

```sql
select name,phone,id from members Where id=1639 and tableid in (89, 92, 156, ..., 364)
```